# d3 Selection merge error in TypeScript: Types of property 'merge' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have this code that does the D3 enter/merge/exit pattern for D3 Stacked Bar Chart. I'm trying to port this over to TypeScript for type safety and getting the following error in merge operation.

**Note**: this code works fine in JavaScript.

Excerpt of the code below, for full minimal reproducible example code see (https://tsplay.dev/m3AdLw) hosted on TypeScript Playground. Note that the error TS(2345) appears in two places where `d3Selection.merge()` is used.

```
import d3Selection, {Selection, ContainerElement} from 'd3-selection'

let chartGroup = d3Selection.select('.chart-group')

let existingLayers = chartGroup.selectAll('.layer')
  .data(dataLayout)

let appendedLayers = existingLayers
  .enter().append('g')
  .classed('layer', true)

let mergedLayers = existingLayers.merge(appendedLayers) // <== TS(2345) error

mergedLayers.exit().remove()
mergedLayers.selectAll('*').remove()
        
mergedLayers
  .attr('fill', d => colorScMkr(d.key))
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
```

TS(2345) error:

```
Argument of type 'Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, BaseType, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, BaseType, unknown>'.
  Types of property 'merge' are incompatible.
    Type '(other: Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, BaseType, unknown>) => Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, BaseType, unknown>' is not assignable to type '(other: Selection<BaseType, unknown, BaseType, unknown>) => Selection<BaseType, unknown, BaseType, unknown>'.
      Types of parameters 'other' and 'other' are incompatible.
        Type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, BaseType, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, BaseType, unknown>'.
          Types of property 'select' are incompatible.
            Type '{ <DescElement extends import(".../node_modules/@types/d3-selection/index").BaseType>(selector: string): import(".../node_modules/@types/d3-selection/ind...' is not assignable to type '{ <DescElement extends import("...node_modules/@types/d3-selection/index").BaseType>(selector: string): import(".../node_modules/@types/d3-selection/ind...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
              Types of parameters 'selector' and 'selector' are incompatible.
                Types of parameters 'groups' and 'groups' are incompatible.
                  Type 'BaseType[] | ArrayLike<BaseType>' is not assignable to type 'SVGGElement[] | ArrayLike<SVGGElement>'.
                    Type 'BaseType[]' is not assignable to type 'SVGGElement[] | ArrayLike<SVGGElement>'.
                      Type 'BaseType[]' is not assignable to type 'SVGGElement[]'.
                        Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type 'SVGGElement'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/mA701w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz - I have updated the question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hmm, there's a bunch of other errors in there, and possibly unrelated code.  Could you pare that down to a *minimal* example where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about?  For me anyway, I know about TypeScript, but not really d3.  If you need someone who knows about both, then hopefully someone like that will come along.  Otherwise, you might want to try to get the example code as focused as possible so that people can dig into it without going down the wrong path.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz you could probably look at this version then: https://tsplay.dev/wOaVym. Other errors are stemming from this merge operation so this is the root of errors any way. See how you go with this skimmed down version

Answer (score 1):

It is a known problem with D3 type library. I use a simple work-around:

```
cost appendedLayers: any = existingLayers
  .enter().append('g')
  .classed('layer', true)

const mergedLayers = existingLayers.merge(appendedLayers);
```

Here is a screenshot from [TS Workbench](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAEwMwGUCmAbNBjGwIB2cAZlBCHAOTIC0AzpjnoZQLABQoksiqAFgEMwaEmQrUk9QcLadw0eMhTYBWUeSq06KrLI7ZCdeCAFQA5sCIBeOAG84MCGABccAEwAGADRwowM3wwrp4+AEYQMI4grgBs3nBYxEFwcXAAvl4cAJA5AO7ACDB8cDYAHB4ecDRwJuaWAHSJ8NW1FgT1fgEwPtk5fGj+gSUpFVU1pm31jmBjrQ3hkeQcHDAAnsJwKDAC2ADWoaYAIgIwAK4UNrbZAJpopgCKMFCuRn4EZtkAEhCnDAD8rgI51CaCgHDgcAAqgRgDAAXAgSAQWD2BCADICAgIeGI5EcNLLdgGAhGRAnASuLY7fZHE7nADaAF1hvTwXY4LcHk9XJRPBV7gBGSg+b6-NCuAUVHzQ2HBKVwDFY1xIUYZNn2TlQR7PKh8jz3NzCiHGk0mmXJAAso1NNrVqPZmu1PL19wtRtFDFcAFZ5TbTYqELFVZl7Rq7lrubqKgKDUa-abza4AOzygOucqVO0QsNcnW8ipuQXun6euAATnlibgkt98YJ7EZhOIpwIuHwRDMaBgAGETmgzNBgGg6AAKBDkynbPYHKDHM4gJkASheT0sZiZdjZUC7pygRAAglAoAJVvVSOQRwQ0LlNl2x+S2RD6iYwGOSgA+OAAeVCACsmPUuxoKso4IIui6PnAHRoAgpzYGgI4jjs2A+AAbqoi4fnAyH1MSKgwCO6EYIuPhLnAAD05HYRgMCggQJzAKhIhnhgJwjhB9rgfUdAYMA8EjgKHH1hwWDwPh-aDsOwydj2fYDn4w73tsHEiV2cAAB7KAAsrsUDDEoOhoNxhkAEKYgg7FsvUCDkAIlhKQIz5CG+Vifgg9KUI6TyUIy4FWce7xoAASj8WIjvS8T5IUfC+VZYACAgCBriOHj1IJhKiXAqzabp+moIZxmqGgaKWOGAA8uKgu+ln2tZtn2RFPh6rFtUBZ2IUthZ9L9IM3RwB4LVPjC-EqewmXjtsGKrD88A2Eo0hGUY1I1U+QEgSO4nyUOdAcU+RGnAhY4+GtmGuYg9JrcyfznZdcCuB4u1QdACCgmO-BCItU67F+UAvVAAByhBoI99QQMQxAMAR80fdxX1fuDkOA1ei4OdhdDYQQqyYZRcBlVYNgAJLo0UoIiJiET9HpuQng4EBwCopITQIcCU2ghLEqSdCoWYeXoFgbaENxjC4COlDhAgqyUIu9RCMIYWUFzZhS1ZJxPKLUVFEaGvFAA1OMdTtE0cB63M7SdIEHFZDLkRQKLPVdEa9tDCbEwNNMxv65MCxRKNisy2AcsWZQSvS9grF0AwQfYIIsA0GYZCnGARpPAdHGZdHpgwAA4gnMxzagwvMO0DD8wRlC4THMBx7nyvsKp8BoOpwBGGuU2gujNgZ7AOc-GAQul-uGAYKLjQnqCtdPkzDlTTNo2ZbLaBYjBbdQHQriYqswyN83eDvCvdBWYvtG29LC-yyHVlhwIEcwaLrGrOPPgp8DGVqSAoKdgg+9b03Ld72Pq9nwfwQmfF6X8AE7QolRPGNgAAqKARxuCQBaL0mFQRkBRBwd+5hl4QPqNvAi0ttwgAgExGq2DP7737kwQew9KAACopbQRIWQx6NosHAPAQ-VeKsbai2IMAIeRoxasT2BPKCqtbYKyeBAICwjch8FhGgWu9c4Dbz-mYMyq9hgUNwdwug1DcC0JHjOcR1lyQuTcnPNSoCYJaLXhjTeNh1G700aYA+tUj6vVPgHReQcL72ifFfG+QdTFPygKnV+xhOH2PXpjH+O81z2KATgpCvil4IHsdjaB+M4DwMQcg1BaijzQEJLozJ7j8FN0Icw0hCEOLlOSSXGhQ9RaMKIWgFh9SykxPcSrdJQdty4DMZI0W6kjRjjiVjLCmlsA6Vtggcx2wPJeSgD5PytVRmUElj4SZjjTqfmynM3SKUNlPi2drI0sz5n1AOFibW7EQZbKdjACZgZ9lYSOfMscEVfJjC+Sch6Ty+HbLeVMg5WUcoLPpAKXywK1aUBeWCj5Z0AXQoGphaoaKfmwvAkAA):
[image]

Comment: Michael Rovinsky - if I do `appendedLayers: any` then it lets me do the merge but I can't do the next bits of code, it still gives me error at `mergedLayers
  .attr('fill', d => colorScMkr(d.key))
  .attr('stroke', 'white')`. Please see the (https://tsplay.dev/m3AdLw) for code.

Comment: The same trick solves all the other problems (sorry for a longURL, SO does not allow link shorteners)

Comment: Thanks Michael - When you say 'this is a known problem with D3 and TypeScript', do you have a reference of any ticket/issue logged somewhere where this is being tracked for a proper solution compared to this workaround? Using `any` at so many places was kind of what I was trying to avoid while migrating codebase to TypeScript

Comment: @ranaalisaeed I asked a similar question a month ago and did not get a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762711/need-to-solve-a-typescript-error-with-d3-code. I also googled other sources and saw a similar ticket in the D3 reporitory without a response... I suppose D3 people don't care about TypeScript... me too :)